# Is there a way to customize a Mac terminal command?

Tags: shell

I would like to customize a Mac terminal command.

For example, regardless the directory I am in, whenever I type 'task1' on command prompt and then enter, it will automatically execute the terminal commands that wrote in a .sh file saved at a location.

I am overwhelmed, I can only run the .sh file by providing its location, which is longer than a 'task1' command.

Answer (score 1):

Put the script in your PATH. You can find a suitable location with `echo $PATH`, and put the script in one of those directories. If none of them look good to you, you can make a new directory somewhere, for example `$HOME/bin`, put the script there, and add `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` to your `.bash_profile` or `.zprofile`, depending on what shell you're using. If you search on StackOverflow for questions related to how PATH works you'll find a lot of good info.

Comment: Changes to `PATH` should be put in `.bash_profile` (or more likely, `.zprofile`, since the OP is more likely to be using `zsh` than `bash`). `PATH` is also already exported, so no need to use `export` to add the directory.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot that PATH is automatically exported. I also tend to forget that people use Zsh.

Comment: I think there are a lot of macOS users that *also* don't know they are using `zsh`.